# make sure an image is loaded while dynamically changing jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm changing the image src of an image node. 
I want to be able to make sure that it's changed before executing somecode. How would i do that?

right now i have

```
function changePic(imgNode, newPic, desc){
    var descNode = $("#description");
    $(imgnode).fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
        $(imgnode).attr("src", newPic);
        $(imgnode).attr("alt", desc)
        descNode.text(desc);
        $(imgnode).fadeTo(500, 1);
    });
}
```

Works great if the server's fast/ a local server. Works terribly if the server's slow, where the image will fade back in before changing...

any idea?

Edit: I'm loading the image when changePic is called. Any better ways to do it?

More: Also why is it not a good idea to put the last line,

> $(imgnode).fadeTo(500, 1);

, outside of the callback function?

Comment: Guessing you're not preloading the images before changePic is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Preload the image](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript), but to be sure it's completely loaded, use the [.load() event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Quote:

> The load event is sent to an element
>   when it and all sub-elements have been
>   completely loaded. This event can be
>   sent to any element associated with a
>   URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes,
>   and the window object.

And don't miss this line:

> It is possible that the load event
>   will not be triggered if the image is
>   loaded from the browser cache. To
>   account for this possibility, we can
>   use a special load event that fires
>   immediately if the image is ready.
>   event.special.load is currently
>   [available as a plugin](http://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js).

I put together an example of how I think you want it to work. I switch between three images I found through Google Images. I bind the load event before I change the src of the image to be sure it's triggered.
http://jsfiddle.net/xdjjR/1/

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can preload image in hidden elements, so that it's loaded with other html. When the source changed such image should be shown immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback param
[doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)
ex from doc:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
 $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```